# how can I get the matching primary key of a value in php?

Tags: php, mysqli, primary-key

Is there a way to get the matching primary key of a value?

I've tried these :

```
$user_id = $mysqli->insert_id($username);
$user_id = $mysqli->primary_key($username);
```

But it's not working. For example, below, in `echo` , I'd like to show the `user_id` of John Grisham, which is a foreign key in another table. And then the categories associated with John Grisham or listed.

```
    <?php

$username = "John Grisham";
//$user_id = $mysqli->insert_id($username);
//$user_id = $mysqli->primary_key($username);

require_once('dbConnect.php');

$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT cat_name FROM category WHERE category.user_id = $user_id");

while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())

    {
        $user_id = $rows['cat_name'];

        echo "<p>categories are $user_id";

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `user_id` is missing in the SELECT query. Your query should be `SELECT user_id, username FROM user ...`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if that will work for what I want to acheive. The user logs in with username. The matching primary key is used as foreign key in another table. Probably best to change my code...

Comment: Depends on your code and what you want to achieve. But you probably want to join the tables.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, edited my question if you have time, thanks.

Comment: Something like `SELECT cat_name FROM category JOIN user ON category.user_id = user.user_uid WHERE user.username = '$username'`